# Python proxy connection fails at urllib splituser _userprog

Tags: python, https, proxy, urllib2, urllib

I'm trying to access an http web service over an orginizational firewall using a proxy.  To access the service, I need to generate a token using an https connection from the service provider. For some reason my connection over a proxy fails, and the python interpreter is throwing an error at line 1072 in urllib which deals with _userprog inside the splituser def:

```
match = _userprog.match(host)
```

The corrosponding error text is 'expected string or buffer'. 
I've added both http_proxy and https_proxy as environment variables using SETX in the command line...

```
SETX http_proxy http:\\user:pw@proxyIP:port
SETX https_proxy https:\\user:pw@proxyIP:port
```

...and added the proxy handlers before the GetToken code of my script:

```
# set proxies
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({
    'http': 'proxy_ip',
    'https': 'proxy_ip'
})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

class GetToken(object):
        def urlopen(self, url, data=None):
        # open url, send response
        referer = "http://www.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest"
        req = urllib2.Request(url)
        req.add_header('Referer', referer)
        if data:
            response = urllib2.urlopen(req, data)
        else:
            response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        return response

    def gentoken(self, username, password,
        referer = 'www.arcgis.com', expiration=60):
        # gets token from referrer
        query_dict = {'username': username,
            'password': password,
            'expiration': str(expiration),
            'client': 'referer',
            'referer': referer,
            'f': 'json'}
        query_string = urllib.urlencode(query_dict)
        token_url = "https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/generateToken"
        token_response = urllib.urlopen(token_url, query_string)
        token = json.loads(token_response.read())
        if "token" not in token:
            print token['messages']
            exit()
        else:
            return token['token']
```

But it still throws the same error.  Any advice would be much appreciated and thank you in advance!

**UPDATE**

Thanks mhawke for the slash suggestion, that changed things...but now I'm getting a new error, here's the traceback:

```
Traceback               
    <module>    C:\Users\tle\Desktop\Scripts\dl_extract2.py 161     
    main    C:\Users\tle\Desktop\Scripts\dl_extract2.py 157     
    __init__    C:\Users\tle\Desktop\Scripts\dl_extract2.py 53      
    gentoken    C:\Users\tle\Desktop\Scripts\dl_extract2.py 40      
    urlopen C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\urllib.py    88      
    open    C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\urllib.py    207     
    open_https  C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\urllib.py    439     
    endheaders  C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\httplib.py   904     
    _send_output    C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\httplib.py   776     
    send    C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\httplib.py   735     
    connect C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\httplib.py   1112        
    wrap_socket C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\ssl.py   350     
    __init__    C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\ssl.py   118     
    do_handshake    C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\ssl.py   293     
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 1] _ssl.c:480: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

**UPDATE 2**

as per mhawke's suggestion, tried using urllib2() instead of urllib() for the https connection for generating the token, which gets rid of the handshake error.  unfortunately now i'm back to square one with the timeout error, except this time it's being thrown in line 1136 of urllib2.  i suppose this is because urllib2 doesn't support https connections.  does this also mean my proxy doesn't support http tunneling, or is there some way i could test for that from my local machine?  in any event, here's the latest traceback:

```
Traceback               
    <module>    C:\Users\tle\Desktop\Scripts\dl_extract2.py 161     
    main    C:\Users\tle\Desktop\Scripts\dl_extract2.py 157     
    __init__    C:\Users\tle\Desktop\Scripts\dl_extract2.py 53      
    gentoken    C:\Users\tle\Desktop\Scripts\dl_extract2.py 40      
    urlopen C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\urllib2.py   126     
    open    C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\urllib2.py   391     
    _open   C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\urllib2.py   409     
    _call_chain C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\urllib2.py   369     
    https_open  C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\urllib2.py   1169        
    do_open C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\urllib2.py   1136        
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060] Ein Verbindungsversuch ist fehlgeschlagen, da die Gegenstelle nach einer bestimmten Zeitspanne nicht richtig reagiert hat, oder die hergestellte Verbindung war fehlerhaft, da der verbundene Host nicht reagiert hat>
```

**UPDATE 3**

This turned out to be a really easy fix -- all that are needed (in my case) are the system environment variables with normal slashes:

```
http_proxy: http://user:pw@proxyip:port
https_proxy: http://user:pw@proxyip:port
```

and the following code removed from the script:

```
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({
    'http': 'proxy_ip',
    'https': 'proxy_ip'
})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

This link explains how and why this works:

http://lukasa.co.uk/2013/07/Python_Requests_And_Proxies/

Comment: Please post the full traceback and show what you are using for 'http': 'proxy_ip'

Comment: Also, rather than using backslashes, you might want to try using slashes in your URLs, i.e. `http://user:pw@proxyIP:port`

Comment: proxy_ip: "192.168.104.103"

Answer (score 0):

The initial problem was apparently resolved by using forward slashes in the proxy environment variables.

For the SSL connection problem, you appear to be using the same port for both http and https proxies. Can your proxy server handle that?

First off, note that in `gentoken()`, `urllib.urlopen()` is used. `urllib.urlopen()` connects to the configured proxy **using SSL** if that scheme is set for the proxy URL. In your case `https_proxy` is `https://user:pw@proxyIP:port`, so a SSL connection will be made to your proxy. It would seem that your proxy doesn't handle that which would explain the failed SSL handshake exception. ** Try using `urllib2.urlopen()` instead.

Also, the python code that creates a `ProxyHandler` is for `urllib2` only, not `urllib`. `urllib` connections will use the environment variable settings.

** It is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html#proxies) that `urllib2()` does not support https through a proxy, but it might work if your proxy supports HTTP tunnelling via `HTTP CONNECT`.

Comment: thanks again for responding, mhawke -- progress and traceback posted in the update.  i guess i'll need to check with IT to see if the proxy supports tunneling.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a really easy fix -- all that are needed (in my case) are the system environment variables with normal slashes:

```
http_proxy: http://user:pw@proxyip:port
https_proxy: http://user:pw@proxyip:port
```

and the following code removed from the script:

```
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({
    'http': 'proxy_ip',
    'https': 'proxy_ip'
})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

This link explains how and why this works:

http://lukasa.co.uk/2013/07/Python_Requests_And_Proxies/